# Dotnet - Using different versions of MSBuild for different projects inside of the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, msbuild

I have been tasked with adding functionality to a legacy project written in VB and utilizing .net Framework 4.8. My skill set is in c# and would prefer to use .net 7. Can these two play nice together? My hope was to be able to add my projects to the existing solution and then add references where I need to and trust in Microsoft magic that these all compile down to the same intermediate language.

I am already seeing issues with just building the existing application now that my projects are in there. (have not tried to reference them yet)

```
  Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2977, 5): [MSB4803] The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild. See https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details.
```

To me this suggests an issue with me using my IDE. Is there a way to configure the projects to use different Versions of MSBuild where appropriate?

Thanks

Comment: It's like playing against a cheater online! Not only will you run into versioning issues with .Net and Core assemblies, you'll also have to deal with c# versioning especially going from c# 7.0 to c# 8.0. Use a net 6 class library and target multiple frameworks. You'll be duping a lot of work or using preprocessor conditioning everywhere. I prefer the former.

Comment: I think the problem is less MSBuild and more that .NET 5+ and .NET Framework are not interoperable as far as I know.  The VB projects may upgrade cleanly to .NET 5+, have you tried?

Comment: Also, from what I've seen, most of the language changes in C# in .NET 5+ are increasingly edge case conveniences where you aren't likely to be significantly hindered by their absence; have you tried just working entirely in .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/resolvecomreference-task?view=vs-2022#msb4803-error

Comment: I literally ran into this issue coming into my position, as we are stuck on .net framework. Word from the wise, while you'll lose a lot of the nice syntax upgrades that .net 5+ has brought, you do have basically everything you need to do the same work in .net framework. If you move to .net core you will need *every* dependency that app uses to be migrated to .net core. It would be a lot of work, and may even be impossible for DLL's you can't touch. You just gotta deal with it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the issue you have is about different versions of MSBuild.

But to answer one question first:

- No, you can't build a solution and use different versions of MSBuild for different projects within the solution. `msbuild mysolution.sln` or `dotnet build mysolution.sln` will use the same build engine for the entire solution.

But different projects within one solution can specify different `ToolsVersion` and different target frameworks.

### .NET implementations

.Net has different [implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/implementations) with different runtimes and libraries.

- ".NET Framework" is an implementation that is Windows only.
- ".NET" (previously ".NET Core") is a cross-platform implementation. (Yes, trying to discuss .NET as a software development platform and .NET as an implementation of said software development platform is confusing.)

You can have a solution that mixes projects with different target frameworks. A solution with projects targeting .NET Framework 4.8 (`net48`) and .NET 7.0 (`net7.0`) can be built with the same version of MSBuild.

But you can't mix dependencies between frameworks. A .NET 7 assembly can't use a .NET Framework 4.8 assembly and vice versa. There is [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0) for that. A project can target or multi-target .NET Standard 2.0 (`netstandard2.0`) so that it can be used by both .NET Framework and .NET.

### MSBuild MSB4803

Did you try to build the solution with the `dotnet` tool? The `dotnet` tool has an embedded copy of MSBuild but `dotnet` is cross-platform, doesn't support .NET Framework, and only knows about .NET SDK installations.

The text of the [MSB4803 error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/resolvecomreference-task?view=vs-2022#msb4803-error) is somewhat misleading and I see the confusion that comes from the use of "version of MSBuild".

When you build a solution from the command line where there is at least one project targeting .NET Framework, you can't use the `dotnet` tool. Instead use `msbuild` directly. When `msbuild` is installed with Visual Studio (or the Visual Studio build tools), it knows about the .NET SDK installations and the .NET framework installations.

- `dotnet build example.sln` is equivalent to `msbuild /t:build example.sln`. The `build` target is the default, so `msbuild /t:build example.sln` is equivalent to `msbuild example.sln`.
- `dotnet clean example.sln` is equivalent to `msbuild /t:clean example.sln`.

Unfortunately, the `dotnet publish` command and the `publish` target are not equivalent.

### Summary

If COM references are being used in the legacy projects, migrating to .NET 7 probably will not be a small effort. For your current task you may need to stick with the code base as it currently is, and make a separate use case and story for migration.